# Using RtspServer from net7mma project to multicast streaming

Tags: c#, network-programming, video-streaming

I am using the the net7mma project to create a media server but I don't know how to use it for multicast streaming.

In my research I see RTSP is an application layer protocol that uses RTP for real data transport and the last one use UDP. The creator of this library doesn't provide free consultation: the only thing he said is "study OSI model my library supports multicast" but I don't know how to use this code. Here is my code.

```
using (RtspServer server = new RtspServer(IPAddress.Any, 554) { Logger = new RtspServerConsoleLogger() })
{
    RtspSource source = new RtspSource("stream", "rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/stream");
    server.TryAddMedia(source);
    server.Start();
    while (!server.IsRunning)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
    foreach (var item in server.MediaStreams)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(item.Ready);
        //Console.WriteLine(item.State);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
    server.Stop();
}
```

If you see the only option is to bind the socket server to local ip address. Maybe I am blocked mine and don't see the problem.

What I want to do is something like VLC do with upd multicast streaming where you set the multicast address of destination.

Comment: Thanks to Alex for the grammar correction

Answer (score 0):

The creator provides free support for bugs, not for system design consultation.

The problem is that you don't understand how multicast transmit and receive work.

You can easily consume either a multicast or unicast stream, you can also publish a multicast stream but you must configure your network appropriately.

The easiest way to achieve multicast if the camera is not multicasting already is to multicast retransmit the unicast stream using network resources.

You can also dedicate a thread as a unicast to multicast repeater (which repeats more then one unicast source, combines or transcodes or a combination of those tasks therein)

That's about all you really need to know....